# Android fetching images from url & storing on devices and then again using it

Tags: android, image, listview

Hi guys i started developing an android application and i am bit confused on which is the best way to accomplish it

---

### Application Flow

when the activity starts it fetches data from the database(sqlite), the database returns a list of data ,this list of data contains text and url for image.

so now i want that as soon as activity start the listview will be populated with the text data and the images.

- The images will be first searched locally  if not present then the images will be fetched from url after the fetching is completed the image will be added to its respective view and also stored on the device
- These images once downloaded should remain on device until the app is uninstalled

---

### Issues

as soon we start the activity the list view gets populated with the data from local database but the images  takes time to download

so i tried asynchronous image loader but the problem was if the activity was started and the device isn't connect to net the image wont show but after that if we connect to internet  these images wont show

---

is their any easier way to handle  the  images  so that if i need to delete these images in future i can. If some one can provide refrence to any project or available libraries to handle these task .Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't the way you are loading the images to list but i suggest you to use picasso a library to load images :
   for url:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

for Resource :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
```

loading from file:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView2);
```

more details are here: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

To download image and save to disk:

```
new ImageDownloader().execute(downloadUrl);


private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return downloadBitmap(param[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result));
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();

    }

    private String downloadBitmap(String url) {
        // initilize the default HTTP client object
        final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //forming a HttoGet request 
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            //check 200 OK for success
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + 
                        " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;

            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    // getting contents from the stream 
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    return SaveBitmapToDir(bitmap);
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                    " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
        } 

        return null;
    }

    private String SaveBitmapToDir(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        File file = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss");
            String dateTime = s.format(new Date());
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            file = new File(path, "MyApp_"+dateTime+".jpg");
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To store key-value pair i suggest you to use android's shared preference to store the image name and the location on the disk.
Here is a tutorial for [Shared Preference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

To store values in shared preferences:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("image name","image path oon disk");
  editor.apply();
```

To retrieve values from shared preferences:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String imagePath = preferences.getString("image name","");
  if(!imagePath.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
  {
    //your action here with the image path
  }
```

Comment: hey did you try the answer i posted ?

Comment: thnx sagar for the code but i need to store more than one image, i tried picasso library which works great but the problem with picasso is it store images inside cache memory so if theirs a way to change setting to make it store it in phone memory or sd card it would be of great help